# Error de SQL (1062): Duplicate entry '58390' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Al cargar la siguente información dentro del área consultas del Sistema Gestor y al darle Ejecutar me aparece esto: Error de SQL (1062): Duplicate entry '58390' for key 'PRIMARY'

INSERT INTO `t_clientes` (`id_cliente`, `nombre`, `apellido`, `edad`, `sexo`) VALUES
    (58390, 'Octavio', 'Ruiz', 27, 'M'),
    (58391, 'Diego', 'Fernandez', 32, 'M'),
    (58392, 'Omar', 'Garcia', 24, 'M'),
    (58393, 'Maria', 'Luna', 26, 'F'),
    (58394, 'Silvia', 'Zuñiga', 35, 'F'),
    (58395, 'Pedro', 'Perez', 22, 'M'),
    (58396, 'Sonia', 'Cardona', 29, 'F'),
    (58397, 'Hugo', 'Mendez', 30, 'M'),
    (58398, 'Sofia', 'Parriego', 26, 'F'),
    (58399, 'Sandra', 'Rivas', 31, 'F');

INSERT INTO `t_productos` (`id_producto`, `modelo`, `marca`, `precio`, `id_proveedor`) VALUES
    (12340, 'Camara', 'Sani', 5350, 45638),
    (12341, 'Pantalla', 'Samsoni', 7820, 45632),
    (12342, 'Audifonos', 'Tronic', 1456, 45633),
    (12343, 'DVD', 'Yashi', 1000, 45631),
    (12344, 'Bluray', 'Moshi', 2000, 45636),
    (12345, 'Celular', 'Moma', 5670, 45639),
    (12346, 'Mouse', 'Razor', 560, 45630),
    (12347, 'Laptop', 'vopoi', 17500, 45635),
    (12348, 'Teclado', 'Razor', 1020, 45634),
    (12349, 'Videogame', 'Sanor', 4567, 45637);

INSERT INTO `t_proveedores` (`id_proveedor`, `nombre`, `apellido`, `dirección`) VALUES
    (45630, 'Manuel', 'Hernández', 'calle coneja #432'),
    (45631, 'Jesus', 'Martinez', 'calle flores #543'),
    (45632, 'Fernanado', 'Lopez', 'calle trejo #654'),
    (45633, 'Ivan', 'Sanchez', 'calle nuvo #765'),
    (45634, 'Rosa', 'Rodriguez', 'calle trolo #876'),
    (45635, 'Merida', 'Rito', 'calle falco #987'),
    (45636, 'Leslie', 'Duran', 'calle mediterraneo #102'),
    (45637, 'Ulises', 'Mendoza', 'calle mar #234'),
    (45638, 'Andrea', 'Guzman', 'calle yate #345'),
    (45639, 'Luz', 'Velazquez', 'calle siempre viva #678');

INSERT INTO `t_sucursal` (`id_sucursal`, `nombre`, `dirección`) VALUES
    (23560, 'Salmons tropia', 'calle tropia #234'),
    (23561, 'Salmons naranjo', 'calle naranjo #345'),
    (23562, 'Salmons artemisa', 'calle artemisa #456'),
    (23563, 'Salmons pichacho', 'calle picacho #567'),
    (23564, 'Salmons fisica', 'calle fisica #678');

INSERT INTO `t_vendedor` (`id_vendedor`, `nombre`, `apellido`, `id_sucursal`, `telefono`) VALUES
    (67840, 'Alberto', 'Ascencio', 23562, 84592730),
    (67841, 'Paulina', 'Rivera', 23562, 89452356),
    (67842, 'Jose', 'Bueno', 23564, 98653265),
    (67843, 'Eduardo', 'Telones', 23564, 98342761),
    (67844, 'Martha', 'Mota', 23561, 14568723),
    (67845, 'Alonso', 'Garcia', 23561, 14789534),
    (67846, 'Diego', 'Trenes', 23563, 34679512),
    (67847, 'Monica', 'Diaz', 23563, 34785612),
    (67848, 'Maricela', 'Hernandez', 23560, 78341267),
    (67849, 'Joel', 'Rico', 23560, 78563453);

INSERT INTO `t_ventas` (`id_venta`, `id_cliente`, `id_producto`, `id_vendedor`, `fecha`) VALUES
    (1, 58391, 12342, 67840, '2015-02-06'),
    (2, 58397, 12344, 67845, '2015-02-06'),
    (3, 58393, 12340, 67846, '2015-02-06'),
    (4, 58390, 12345, 67843, '2015-02-06'),
    (5, 58392, 12343, 67849, '2015-02-06'),
    (6, 58395, 12347, 67842, '2015-02-06'),
    (7, 58399, 12346, 67848, '2015-02-06'),
    (8, 58394, 12341, 67844, '2015-02-06'),
    (9, 58398, 12348, 67847, '2015-02-06'),
    (10, 58396, 12349, 67841, '2015-02-06'),
    (11, 58391, 12344, 67840, '2015-03-06'),
    (12, 58397, 12340, 67845, '2015-03-06'),
    (13, 58393, 12345, 67846, '2015-03-06'),
    (14, 58390, 12343, 67843, '2015-03-06'),
    (15, 58392, 12347, 67849, '2015-03-06'),
    (16, 58395, 12346, 67842, '2015-03-06'),
    (17, 58399, 12341, 67848, '2015-03-06'),
    (18, 58394, 12348, 67844, '2015-03-06'),
    (19, 58398, 12349, 67847, '2015-03-06'),
    (20, 58396, 12342, 67841, '2015-03-06'),
    (21, 58391, 12340, 67840, '2015-04-06'),
    (22, 58397, 12345, 67845, '2015-04-06'),
    (23, 58393, 12343, 67846, '2015-04-06'),
    (24, 58390, 12347, 67843, '2015-04-06'),
    (25, 58392, 12346, 67849, '2015-04-06'),
    (26, 58395, 12341, 67842, '2015-04-06'),
    (27, 58399, 12348, 67848, '2015-04-06'),
    (28, 58394, 12349, 67844, '2015-04-06'),
    (29, 58398, 12342, 67847, '2015-04-06'),
    (30, 58396, 12344, 67841, '2015-04-06'),
    (31, 58391, 12345, 67840, '2015-05-06'),
    (32, 58397, 12343, 67845, '2015-05-06'),
    (33, 58393, 12347, 67846, '2015-05-06'),
    (34, 58390, 12346, 67843, '2015-05-06'),
    (35, 58392, 12341, 67849, '2015-05-06'),
    (36, 58395, 12348, 67842, '2015-05-06'),
    (37, 58399, 12349, 67848, '2015-05-06'),
    (38, 58394, 12342, 67844, '2015-05-06'),
    (39, 58398, 12344, 67847, '2015-05-06'),
    (40, 58396, 12340, 67841, '2015-05-06'),
    (41, 58391, 12345, 67840, '2015-07-06'),
    (42, 58397, 12343, 67845, '2015-07-06'),
    (43, 58393, 12347, 67846, '2015-07-06'),
    (44, 58390, 12341, 67843, '2015-07-06'),
    (45, 58392, 12348, 67849, '2015-07-06'),
    (46, 58395, 12349, 67842, '2015-07-06'),
    (47, 58399, 12342, 67848, '2015-07-06'),
    (48, 58394, 12344, 67844, '2015-07-06'),
    (49, 58398, 12340, 67847, '2015-07-06'),
    (50, 58396, 12345, 67841, '2015-07-06');

Comment: En la parte del código que proporcionas el numero "58390" solo esta una vez; mira en todo tu script buscando ese número,alguna otra parte tienes un INSERT INTO t_clientes donde ya usaste ese valor.

Comment: Revisa cada sentencia amigo a mi me paso igual, revisa y hay que agregar ´telefono´ y ´direccion´ hay que quitarle la tilde

Comment: duplicate entry es un error por tratar de ingresar un valor que tiene el atributo de primary key o de unique por lo tanto no permite duplicados

Comment: yo tengo el error, pero quisiera que en vez de sobreescribirle quiero que me de un alert, alguien me ayude con una funcion, alguien me ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Ya tienes un cliente en la tabla `t_clientes` con `id_cliente` igual a 58390. Como `id_cliente` es la clave primaria, no pueden haber dos registros con el mismo valor.

Tienes varias opciones:

- Utiliza un `update` para modificar/acualizar el registro existente.
- Haz un `insert` dejando el campo `id_cliente` a `null` para crear una nueva entrada (siempre que tengas configurada la tabla para generar el id automáticamente).
- Añade un [`on duplidate key update`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) si estás utilizando MySQL (no sé si se puede con otros DBMS).
- Si estás cargando un volcado para restaurar una copia de seguridad, haz un `truncate` para vaciar antes las tablas.